# Visual Studio 2013: Window.PreviousTab changes design/split/source views instead of tabs

Tags: visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013 Professional, the keyboard shortcut which is supposed to toggle to the previous tab, bound through `Window.PreviousTab`, seems to be toggling the Design/Split/Source views:
[image: Design | Split | Source]

I went ahead and tried to isolate the problem by removing everything connected to the default keybindings of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Page Down</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Page Down</kbd>. I also completely removed all keybindings for `Window.PreviousTab` and `Window.NextTab` so that nothing changes the windows.

I then bound <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to `Window.NextTab` and it worked fine for going to the next tab. Then I removed that and bound <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to `Window.PreviousTab` and it toggled the Design/Split/Source view instead of the tab. I removed that and bound it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> and it had the same effect. There are no other bindings using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.

What is causing this, and how can I fix the problem? Is it a bug?

The only extension I have is PHP Tools for Visual Studio.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem, and the PHP Tools website does mention those support for those views (not the hotkeys though), maybe they've hooked something in, try disabling the extension.

Comment: it's mind-boggling to me how this is the only mention of this issue I could find in a google search.  I've tried disabling HTML Designer.   It removes the split/source buttons, but doesn't fix the problem -- you still can't Window.PreviousTab from an aspx :|

Comment: You're experiencing it too? Do you have the PHP tools add-on?

Comment: I've also experienced this behavior with VS2012, and I do not have PHP tools add-on installed, this smells like a bug, I wish someone could find a workaround

Comment: I've had a look around and it seems like this is actually intended behaviour(ish). I found [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_xpRAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA385&lpg=PA385&dq=visual+studio+window.previoustab+html&source=bl&ots=00YKs__o-v&sig=C2bVYsyDKZfontndZrEhfQ96M2Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XrsCVaT9Isq3aa2XgMgB&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=visual%20studio%20window.previoustab%20html&f=false) and next/previous tab move tabs in the *document* or window. Still annoying as hell though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to look for it for a while, this was [intentionally removed](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/796625/visual-studio-2013-missing-design-source-and-split-buttons).  For a good reason, this is legacy.  It didn't get any love at VS2010, just the minimum to still make it functional, WebForms is not Microsoft's priority.  Very high odds that you can't fix this and the keybinding was hard-coded in the extension.

But don't take bad news from an SO user, nobody ever likes that, get it from horse's mouth.  Also a basic way they find out what their customers care about.  Post the issue at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?